# monotouch compiling monotouch-bindings facebook api

Tags: ios, facebook, git, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need the facebook api wrapper from the monotouch-bindings, so I've downloaded from github the whole package of the [monotouch-bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings).

I cannot compile the `facebook dll` (I'm doing it on a macosx 10.8.3).

The make command from the folder `monotouch-bindings-master/facebook` gives me an error:

```
git clone git@github.com:facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git
Cloning into 'facebook-ios-sdk'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
make[1]: *** [facebook-ios-sdk] Error 128
make: *** [build-binding] Error 2
```

I also tried with `sudo` make but I get the same error.
I've checked if the `github.com:facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git` exists and it seems it does exist.

Comment: Have you tried the prebuilt Xamarin.Social library?  It includes FB API support.  http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that your actual problem here lies in `git`.

A quick search in Google yielded this useful article from Github: [Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey).

I would suspect that if you look into it, you will file the [Make sure you have a key and SSH is using it](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey#make-sure-you-have-a-key-and-ssh-is-using-it) will fix your problem.

That's not to say that this won't fix All your problems, but it should fix this one.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the github client before running the make command and the compile succeded.

Thanks for your answer!!!